# Glassfish. java ee. После прохождения авторизации с использованием формы не устанавливается сессия

Tags: java, java-ee, glassfish

Всем привет. Есть web приложение с закрытой частью, и авторизацией с использованием jdbcRealm. После прохождения авторизации по ссылке на страницу в закрытой части, не устанавливается сессия, и в строке адреса:

```
http://<ip>:8080/<корневая директория>/;jsessionid=91f8733208ea8cfeedd981772aa0
```

хотя должно переходить на запрошенную страницу:

```
http://<ip>:8080/<корневая директория>/<закрытая директория>/<запрошенная страница>.xhtml
```

На локальном сервере проблем нет, приложение работает корректно. Проблема появилась после перехода на VPS

Прикладываю web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>userLim</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>application</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>userRole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>jdbcRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginerror.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>userRole</role-name>
</security-role>
```

и glassfish-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>userRole</role-name>
    <group-name>user</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code. 
</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Не могу разобраться, два моих сервера одинаково сконфигурированы.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была только с браузером Chrome, при использовании https проблема больше не наблюдается.

Comment: @HamSter это *ответ* автора вопроса. Других ответов и вообще активности других участников ни в вопросе, ни в ответе нет. Бессмысленно в такой советовать участнику оставлять замечания себе же или просить внести уточнения у самого себя.